# Prove that the volume of the whole flow inside the pipe is equal to $k \pi R^4/2.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

When a liquid flows inside a cylindrical tube, the friction inside the pipe wall makes its movement slower.  This fact causes the flow to be faster, when closer to the center of pipe, than next to the wall.

According to a formula ( which its name is not important here ), we can assume that the liquid flows on cylindrical layers with a constant speed which is equal to $v(r)=k(R^2-r^2)$. Here, $R$ is the radius of the pipe, $r$ is the distance to the center of the pipe and $k$ is a constant number which depends on the liquid and the pipe.

Prove that the volume of the whole flow inside the pipe ( The volume which crosses the cross section at each moment ) is equal to $k \pi R^4/2.$

Note : I don't even understand the question.  But i think it must be related to integration.  But the problem is that i don't know what to integrate.

Comment: do you know what is $r$?

Comment: @ArnaldoNascimento I'm so sorry i forgot to write it . I corrected my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate the flow of $\vec{v}=v(r)\hat{u}_z$ through a section $\Sigma$ of the cylinder. In this notation, $\hat{u}_z$ is just the versor  parallel to the cylinder axis.
If we call $\hat{n}$ the normal versor to $\Sigma$, we get:
$$\Phi_{\Sigma}(\vec{v}) = \int \langle \vec{v},\hat{n} \rangle d\Sigma = \int_0 ^ R v(r)\cdot 2\pi r dr$$
since the two vectors are parallel and for a circle we have $d\Sigma = 2\pi r dr$ **(*)**. Completing the previous calculation returns the desired result.

**(*)** Intuitively it is because you're "summing" all the circular annuli with infinitesimal width $dr$.
If you want to be more precise, you just have to specify the parametrization of the circle and calculate its Jacobian. Then you get: 
$$\int_0 ^{2\pi} \int_0 ^R v(r) dr d \theta = \int _0 ^ R v(r) \cdot 2 \pi dr$$

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you do the calculation without nested integration? ( just using 1 integration ... )

Comment: The double integral was just to motivate why you have that $2 \pi r dr$. By the way, when you're calculating integrals over a surface, you always have a double integral, since you have to calculate: $$\int f(u,v) | \det Jac \phi(u,v)| du dv$$ where $\phi$ is a parametrization of the surface.  
This one was a fortunate case where we have dependency only on the radius $r$, so the integral over the coordinate $\theta$ is calculated instantly.